# What battery connector is this?

Tags: identification, connector

A soldered-in battery for a device of mine has run flat. Rather than replace the whole device, I'd like to replace just the battery, with a 'user-serviceable' substitute.

I've found the correct 3 V (CR-2/3AZ) battery, but I can't find the corresponding female connector. Could anyone advise on the model shown in the picture?

My plan is to solder this female connector to the existing wires, previously attached to aforementioned dead battery.

[image: 3v]

[image]

Comment: Looks JST. What's the pin pitch and overall connector dimensions?

Comment: @winny I agree JST - These are pictures from the catalog, not my possession, so unsure. I've leaning towards JST 2.0?

Comment: Without dimensions, your guess is as good as anyone else's ...

Comment: "My plan is to solder this female connector to the existing wires"  Eeeh? Just cut the damn thing off, peel & solder. Careful not to short the wires though, so peel one at a time.

Comment: As for what the connector might be, it's almost certainly one of the usual suspects: JST, Molex, TE, maybe Hirose.

Answer (score 3):

I use that exact connector all the time. Assuming it is 2mm pitch, it is a [JST PH series](https://www.jst.com/products/crimp-style-connectors-wire-to-board-type/ph-connector/). If you don't want to go to the trouble of buying housing and crimp pins, you can find cable assemblies [like this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/261).

*(Be cautious about polarity. I have found that some vendors connect the black and red wires opposite that of what you have pictured.)*

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up purchasing.

Comment: Or use the IDC version which has superior quality to the crimp version, although you need a tool for them. Also these wires look slightly too thick to be used with PH series (should be AWG26 something like that).