# What connector is this?

Tags: identification, connector

Which connector series might this be?
The PCB part is broken and I need to replace it.
It's a 2mm pitch.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Top view. Check footprint
[image]

Comment: Probably JST PH series. JST PH is 2mm on center. If the spacing is not 2 mm on-center then it is not JST PH series.

Comment: It is not JST PH. On the PCB header, the two slots on the front where the connector locks, go all the way through to the bottom. This is not the case on the PH.

Comment: JST PH may be the most widely cloned/copied connector series there is. Even if it is not JST PH maybe you could replace it with one. And, if necessary, replace the housing, too. Just a thought, hence I am leaving this as a comment not an answer.

Comment: Not necessarily a duplicate question, but same connector as https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/640146/2028

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a *JST PH*.

The female PH has a wide cut out and two holes at the bottom (2 mm pin spacing), whereas the XH has two slots from the top towards the bottom (2.5 mm pin spacing).

Here is an example with 6 pins

[image: PH 6 pin socket]
PH vs XH
[image: XJ 6 pin socket]

There's a good reference at [mattmillan.com](http://www.mattmillman.com/info/crimpconnectors/common-jst-connector-types/) which helps to identify different types of JST connectors.

A female *JST PH* has one slot (or rather a cut-out) going down in the middle of the female. Which corresponds to the bar going down the middle of the male (as can be seen on [your photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Mctv.jpg)). Either side of the slot/cut-out are two small holes at the bottom.

See the *top left* female connector in this photo from [Common JST Connector Types](http://www.mattmillman.com/info/crimpconnectors/common-jst-connector-types/) - [PH (2.0mm pitch)](https://www.mattmillman.com/info/crimpconnectors/common-jst-connector-types/#ph):

[image: JST PH 2.0 mm female connectors]

To sum up:

- Your male connector has a bar down the center, which corresponds to the long slot in the middle on the female connector.
- Your male connector also has two small lumps/keys then correspond to the two small holes either side of the long slot on the female.
- Admittedly your female connector has rather elongated holes that make them look like slots, but they are just long holes, and the shorter holes on a replacment will suit just fine.

Answer (score 1):

My [Identiconn](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=lo_prof_1r_w2b_conn_2&fl=0000000010000000000000002000000000-108-%7C%7C2%7C%7C%7C) identified these connectors.

They are industry-standard made by multiple manufacturers. All are dimensionally compatible with yours.

- MANUF. - SERIES
- Adam tech - [2SH + 2CH](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/4/page_234-240-12264.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/4b795ftv)
- [JST](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=199) - [PH + PH PHN (crimp)](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/ePH.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/bbdr3m4n)
- Molex - 89400 + 87369 - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/531zm38z)
- Sullins - [SWR201 + SWH201](https://s3.amazonaws.com/catalogspreads-pdf/PAGE130-131%202mm%20SWT201%2C%20SWH201%20CRIMP%20TERMINAL%2C%20HOUSING%20WAFER.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/vt82b070)
- [TE](https://www.te.com/usa-en/products/connectors/pcb-connectors/wire-to-board-connectors/intersection/high-performance-interconnects.html?tab=pgp-story) - [HPI-2 (1r 4w)](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=1-1773713-2_HPI_QRG_EN&DocType=DS&DocLang=EN) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/v4z3q27r)
- [Wurth](https://www.we-online.com/catalog/en/em/connectors/wire-to-board/wr_wtb/wr_wtb_2_00_mm) - WR-WTB 620 - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/20tw12mf)

[image: Sullins SWH201-NULN-S02-UU-WH]

{Digikey}

[image: Sullins 292133-2]

{Digikey}

The length of the two slots on the wide face is irrelevant because all that matters is the top edge of the slot. That's where the friction nubs on the plug rest when mated.